# MYSQL - Can't get the proper result

Tags: mysql

I have the bellow example of a product table. Each product can contain several references and prices. I would like to show in each name the lowest price and the number of different prices for each.

**Table**

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`ref` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`id_brand` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
`price` float NOT NULL,
`discount` float NOT NULL
```

---

**Data**

```
('1', 'Banana', 'AAN0L9HA33', '1', '1', '40', '0');
('3', 'Banana', 'AAN0L9HA31', '1', '1', '40', '0');
('4', 'Banana', 'ACL0M0BP30', '1', '1', '20', '0');
('5', 'Rice', 'ACL0M0BP40', '1', '1', '60', '0');
('6', 'Rice', 'ACL0M0BP20', '1', '1', '60', '0');
```

---

**Expected Result**

```
'Banana', 1, 1, 20, 0, (total: 2)
'Rice', 1, 1, 50, 0, (total: 1)
```

I've tested Inner join's and subqueries but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to solve this.

To solve this situation I've made the first query with a simple list of the product and then, with PHP, while on mysql_fetch_array, added another query where that was fetched by 'name', ordered the price, grouped by 'price' and then, used the mysql_num_rows to know how many prices there was.

It works but its not that good for the server processors. :)

Thank you for the help.

Cheers!

Comment: can you create an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Hi, here you have. Thank you :)  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ed4c/3

Comment: Note that typically money is DECIMAL, and names (and probably refs too) are VARCHAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is query without brand and cat

```
SELECT name,MIN(price),COUNT(DISTINCT price)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY name
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ed4c/7/0

this is same query with brand+cat

```
SELECT * FROM
(        
    SELECT name,MIN(price) as best_price,COUNT(DISTINCT price) as total
    FROM p_produto
    GROUP BY name        
) tbest
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT name,price,id_cat,id_brand
    FROM p_produto
    GROUP BY name,price
) tcb
ON (tcb.name = tbest.name) AND (tcb.price = tbest.best_price)
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ed4c/12/0

Comment: Remove `id_brand,id_cat`from your `SELECT` statement and you get it ! :) (or add it in your `GROUP` statement)

Comment: Once again, thanks a lot for the help. I've tested in a mora complex database and it works like a charm. :)